# Is there an easy to use open source pretrained or commercial API for object classification and localization in images?

Tags: image-processing, api, image-recognition

There are a number of commercial APIs such as Clarifai and Google Cloud Vision that provide image tagging, however they don't provide any location or size (bounding box) for the detected objects, they simply just provide tags for the image as a whole.

Is there any easy to use open source solution (but preferably a commercial API) that can detect objects (and doesn't need to be trained - can detect thousands of every day objects out of the box) and return their bounding box as well, similar to this image:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8EeL.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer but I recommend caffe

Comment: I've looked at caffe and it does look interesting, however as mentioned above, I am looking for a solution that can show where the tags appear in the image - and caffe doesn't seem to have that localization feature...unless I've missed something.

Comment: Oh sorry yes I missed that. You could do it but it would take custom coding. I think I did something close to that a year ago but it was using tensorflow and not easy at all. I suggest you ask on Kaggle and / or the caffe listserv.